# Touchpad problem on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: touchpad, drag-and-drop

I have  a laptop running Ubuntu 18.04 but the touchpad seems very sensitive. When I try to use touchpad after a couple of seconds the cursor drags down. It is almost like it remembers one touch from where I left. Laptop is ASUS vivobook K510U. Thanks for help.